# Get rid of AM/PM in the time format in Delphi Rio 10.3 (from 12:00 PM to 12:00 only)

Tags: delphi, dbgrid

I referred to this link related to time format http://www.delphibasics.co.uk/RTL.asp?Name=formatdatetime and I find the FormatDateTime('t', myDate) useful to me. I need to get the number of hours between TimeIn and TimeOut.

However, when I tried to use in both DBGridEh and Dataset level, which happens to be available in the DisplayFormat properties, I still get the AM/PM in the fields.

I tried as well to change the data type at the back-end database MySQL to Char(5), no avail as well.

Looks to me that the FormatDateTime('t', MyDate) is not working to me.

By the way, I also tried to EditMask to both Dataset and DBGridEh level but the same result. I still couldn't get rid of the AM/PM in the time "12:00 PM" rather I need "12:00" only.

Comment: Formatdatetime('HH:NN', MyDate); should work just fine (given that your db backend field is actually datetime). NEVER EVER use char to represent datetime...

Comment: @whosrdaddy Yes, I realized that I should never use char. Thanks for that. However, I tried your suggestion Formatdatetime('HH:NN', MyDate), it still not working. Here's the code I used — DataSet['TtlRegularHours'] := FormatDateTime('HH:NN', AmTime + PmTime);.

Comment: @Mel "*I need to get the number of hours between TimeIn and TimeOut*" - so why are you using `FormatDateTime()` at all? Consider using [`HoursBetween()`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.DateUtils.HoursBetween) instead, and then you can format that number however you want. Or better, don't format it at all. Store it in the DB  as an integer instead of as a string or a date/time

Comment: @RemyLebeau Thank you! Got it! Can you post your answer here so I can mark it answered already.